# Multiple Hidden Services?

Tags: tor-button, tor-network

How can I create two or more hidden services with one instance of Tor? Is the following correct or do they need different ports?

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/www/tor/test1/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:44403
HiddenServiceDir /var/www/tor/test2/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:44403
```

Where test1 and test2 are different websites with different (.onion) host names.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this will work. With your configuration, you'll have two onion domains that send traffic on port 80 to the same web server (`127.0.0.1:44403`), so they'll both display the same contents.

Comment: so this configuration will show the exact same content, but have two different onion addresses? That’s not what I need.. how is it that you would have two entirely different websites that are completely independent of each other? (Maybe) Keep one on the regular ports and have the other one on different ports? I need test1 to have its own .onion (TLD) and test2 to have its own .onion, each with their own corresponding directories. Can i just make the “test1” ports 80 and 443 and change “test2” to be ports 81 and 444?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have two web servers right? One for each website? Can't you just point the second onion service to your second web server? Right now you have both onion services pointing to the same localhost web server.

Comment: I’m wanting to set this up as one server with two separate directories. Simple HTML and css websites so don’t need Apache or anything like that.